# What's the best way to embed a generated value in TypeScript at compile-time?

Tags: typescript

I would like to embed the Git SHA and version number into a program at compile-time so it can be retrieved via an interface at runtime. `process.env` contains environment variables at runtime. Is there something similar to store computed values at compile-time?

Comment: `process.env` is certainly available at compile time if you're talking about compiling TS to JS

Comment: `process.env` is transpiled literally, not evaluated at compile-time, unless I'm mistaken.